# error: index out of range

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

The following code show 'string index out of range' error for line "sub=sub+s[j]":

```
    s=raw_input()
    l=len(s)
    row=int(l**0.5)
    column=row+1
    i=0
    while i<column:
        j=i
        sub=""
        while j<len:
            sub=sub+s[j]
            j=j+column
        print sub,
        sub=""
        i=i+1
```

What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking to use:

```
while j < len(s):
```

Instead of:

```
while j<len:
```

As Lex S. also stated, len is a reserved builtin in Python, so that's why this code even works (you never declared a "len" variable).

As he also stated, you need to leave comments and use descriptive variable names so we can determine what in fact your code is doing. I'd like to add that you should be putting spaces between operators. So instead of

```
column=row+1
```

it should be

```
column = row + 1
```

You can read the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

`len` is a builtin function and the conditional `j<len` will always be true.  Change the line to:

```
while j < l:
```

You should also try to make the variable names more descriptive.  Using single letter variable names is an anti-pattern <s>in Python</s>.